# sticky-top class not working. Bootstrap-4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sticky

I have a row which contains two column. I want the column on left to be fixed on scrolling and only right column should be scrolled. I don't want to use position fixed because its taking column out of the document flow.

I have come across bootstrap class sticky-top which is not working in my case.

I referred other anwers and this answer but I don't think any of column's(column which I want to be fixed) parent has overflow property set.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57711801/4494813

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-3 sticky-top">

            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-12 mb-5">
                    <div class="border border-secondary px-3 py-2">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter Deal ID Here">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 w-100">Lookup Deal</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 mb-5">
                    <div class="border border-secondary px-3 py-2">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter EU Name Here">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter Partner Name Here">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 w-100">Add Revenue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="phsc_data" class="col-9 table-active">
            <!--BASE REBATES-->
            <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-light table-hover">
                    <caption class="font-weight-bold pl-2">Base Rebates</caption>
                    <thead class="">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">LOB</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
                        <th scope="col">Revenue</th>
                        <th scope="col">Rebate</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>CSG</td>
                        <td>
                            <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                                <option value="">ABC</option>
                                <option value="">DEF</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>Client A</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345"></td>
                        <td>185</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having a placeholder div so that the sticky behavior doesn't offset the normal div ?

you would have to use `position:fixed` for the sticky behavior as shared in the **code snippet** below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row mb-4">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 sticky-placeholder">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 sticky-top">
      <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
          <div class="border border-secondary px-3 py-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter Deal ID Here">
            <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 w-100">Lookup Deal</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mb-5">
          <div class="border border-secondary px-3 py-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter EU Name Here">
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" placeholder="Enter Partner Name Here">
            <button class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 w-100">Add Revenue</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="phsc_data" class="col-12 col-sm-9 table-active">
      <!--BASE REBATES-->
      <p>
        What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
        recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
        'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
        infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
      </p>
      <p>
        Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
        in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
        1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
      </p>
      <p>
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
        from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
      </p>
      <p>
        Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a
        passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the
        Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour,
        or non-characteristic words etc.
      </p>
      <p>
        What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
        recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
      <p>
        Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using
        'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their
        infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
      </p>
      <p>
        Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College
        in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and
        1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.
      </p>
      <p>
        The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions
        from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
      </p>
      <p>
        Where can I get some? There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a
        passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the
        Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour,
        or non-characteristic words etc.
      </p>
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-light table-hover">
          <caption class="font-weight-bold pl-2">Base Rebates</caption>
          <thead class="">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">LOB</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Product Category</th>
              <th scope="col">Revenue</th>
              <th scope="col">Rebate</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>CSG</td>
              <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="" id="">
                  <option value="">ABC</option>
                  <option value="">DEF</option>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td>Client A</td>
              <td><input class="form-control" type="number" value="12345"></td>
              <td>185</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  @media screen AND (min-width:576px) {
    .sticky-div {
      position: fixed;
      overflow-y: scroll
    }
    .sticky-placeholder {
      display: none
    }
  }
</style>
```