# how to make left or right section sticky for some time being?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to understand how we can fix the position of the particular section for time being just like in the below example.

https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-watch/apple-watch?option.watch_cases=MWT32LL/A&option.watch_bands=MXP02AM/A&preSelect=false&product=Z0YQ&step=detail#

In the above link, the apple watch product is fixed while the right content moves to some extent, and then the whole page moves.

I tried working on this by making the left side fixed by providing class **sticky-top**

```
<div class ="container">
<div class="row">
<div class = "col-sm-3 sticky-top">
<h1> left container</h1>
</div>
<div class = "col-sm-9 offset-2"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I didnt put the whole code just a essence of what I tried and failed to acoomplish.

Comment: What browser are you using? This answer may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52580656/2570277

Comment: @Shivani, could you share the full source code? In order to have the sticky worked, you should have the content that has the height over the window's height (100vh).

Answer (score 1):

What you have to put additionally is to add **height** CSS attribute in the sticky part. (left or right)
Please refer to this: https://jsfiddle.net/kevindev725/6y7kmbh1/44/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="left sticky-top">
    left sticky content
  </div>
  <div clss="right">
    right scrollable content
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap will set `position: stikcy` with `sticky-top` class, but you should have the fixed size (whatever you want according to the content height) for the left sticky content. It's okay if `height:fit-content` or `height: 100px` or whatever you want to show the height of content while scrolling right side.
Hopefully this would be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.left {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.centered img {
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="split left">
  <div class="centered">
      
       <p>Some text.</p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="split right">
  <div class="centered">
   <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
       <p>Some text.</p>
    <p>Some text here too.</p>
  </div>
</div>
     
</body>
</html>
```

I think this skeleton is enough to achive what u want